# alert undefined in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am new to Cordova. I have completed the installation process of Cordova 3.5.0 and hello World program is working fine for me. But when i am trying to use some Cordova API's like Alert it gives me the following error in logcat:

```
07-18 03:42:07.060: D/CordovaActivity(1183): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index1.html)
07-18 03:42:08.170: D/CordovaWebViewClient(1183): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index1.html)
07-18 03:42:08.170: D/CordovaActivity(1183): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index1.html)
07-18 03:42:08.410: D/CordovaActivity(1183): onMessage(spinner,stop)
07-18 03:42:10.180: D/CordovaActivity(1183): onMessage(spinner,stop)
07-18 03:42:12.740: D/CordovaLog(1183): file:///android_asset/www/index1.html: Line 28 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'alert' of undefined
```

This is my HelloWorld.java

```
package com.example.hello;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloWorld extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        //super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");



        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index1.html", 5000);
    }
}
```

And This is my index1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Notification Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Empty
    }

    // alert dialog dismissed
        function alertDismissed() {
            // do something
        }

    // Show a custom alertDismissed
    //
    function showAlert() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            alertDismissed,         // callback
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Manifest file:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.example.hello" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="HelloWorld" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    </manifest>

my config.xml file:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop" />
    <feature name="App">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification" />
</feature>
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index1.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you added the notification plugin? See [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html) for documentation.

Comment: I am not able to do this step:cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-vibration.git   It gives me this error:F:\cordova\CordovaProjects\hello>cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git
Fetching plugin "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-dialogs.git" via git clone
Error: "git" command line tool is not installed: make sure it is accessible on your PATH.

Comment: You have to download git from http://msysgit.github.io and make sure you check the option “use git from the windows command prompt”.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add dialogs plugin first. 
You can add it using below command.

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```